# Alternative for zip in python 3?

Tags: python, merge, concatenation

Alternative for zip in python 3?

```
from itertools import zip_longest 
list_1 = [["ele1"],["ele_2"],["ele_3"]]
list_2 = [["ele4"],["ele_5"]]

result = [[x for x in t if x is not None] for t in zip_longest(list_1,list_2)]
print(result)
```

I got output as

```
[[['ele1'], ['ele4']], [['ele_2'], ['ele_5']], [['ele_3']]]
```

Expected Output:

```
[['ele1'], ['ele4']], [['ele_2'], ['ele_5']], [['ele_3']]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @ yatu i mentioned please see the code again

Comment: Your output and expected output are the same..

Comment: but i want alternative for zip

Comment: and i expected output in nested list , but i got nested list of nested list

Comment: `[['ele1'], ['ele4']], [['ele_2'], ['ele_5']], [['ele_3']]` is a tuple `([['ele1'], ['ele4']], [['ele_2'], ['ele_5']], [['ele_3']])` and not a list

Comment: Unclear. Do you want the same result, but without `zip` (or `zip_longest`), or do you want a different result? In the latter case, what should be the type of your result? A list, or a tuple, or just a string or a printed output?

Comment: Just do `print(*result)` in your code and you will get the output you need. Rest everything stays the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid using zipping both lists, the way I would do this is by appending the values from both lists within a `try`/`except` clause, and appending values from `list_2` (or `list_1` if it were the shortest of both) defined as an iterator, avoiding in this way having to `zip` both lists while iterating:

```
# iterate over the longest list. Define other as iterator
l2 = iter(list_2)
out = [[] for _ in range(len(list_1))]
for ix, i in enumerate(list_1): 
    try:
        out[ix].append(i)
        out[ix].append(next(l2))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Gives:

```
print(out)
[[['ele1'], ['ele4']], [['ele_2'], ['ele_5']], [['ele_3']]]
```

Comment: Yes the idea would be to iterate over the longest lsit @tobias_k , mayb should make it clearer. Can't think of another way though avoiding `zip_longest`

Comment: break has one extra indentation

Answer (score 0):

You could also collect your two (or more) lists in another list and use a nested list comprehension to emulate the behavious of `zip_longest`.

```
>>> lists = [list_1, list_2] # an also be more than two lists
>>> [[lst[i] for lst in lists if i < len(lst)]
...  for i in range(max(map(len, lists)))]
...
[[['ele1'], ['ele4']], [['ele_2'], ['ele_5']], [['ele_3']]]
```

(And if you swap `max` for `min` in the above expression, you get `zip`.)

If you want to print the result without the outermost `[...]`:

```
>>> print(', '.join(map(str, _)))                                          
[['ele1'], ['ele4']], [['ele_2'], ['ele_5']], [['ele_3']]
```